# how to prove that $BB^H$ must be invertible.If $\mathbf B$ is a $N$ by $M$ matrix,and $N<M$

Tags: matrices, vectors, inverse

If $\mathbf B$ is a $N$ by $M$ matrix,and $N<M$.how to prove that $BB^H$ must be invertible.

Here we assume that $N$ is the rank(B)

Answer (score 0):

$B B^H$ is always Hermitian and positive semidefinite.  Note that $x^H B B^H x = \|B^H x\|^2$, so $x^H B B^H x = 0$ implies $B^H x = 0$.  If $B$ (and thus $B^H$) has rank $N$, this can only happen for $x=0$, so $B B^H$ is positive definite and therefore invertible.

Comment: you mean that if B is full rank,it means that its kernel must be zero vector,so x must be zero vector ,so....why does it mean B must be invertible?

Comment: $B$ is not invertible.  $B^H$ is $M \times N$ and has rank $N$, so its kernel is $\{0\}$, by the [Rank-Nullity Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).